# How can I automatically forward e-mail to Picasaweb from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, picasa-web-albums

Picasaweb has an email dropbox feature that allows you to send email with pictures or videos to a special address, and have them automatically appear in Picasa.

I want to setup a filter in Gmail that will automatically forward certain emails with pictures to Picasa.  In order to setup auto-forwarding in Gmail, they send a confirmation mail to the target address with a confirmation link.

The problem is that when this mail is sent to the Picasaweb dropbox, I don't get it, because that only shows me pictures or videos that were sent, and discards everything else.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this email dropbox is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Its too bad that Google now requires forwarding addresses to be verified, but it was likely a huge security issue when they previously didn't.

The same question has been [asked](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=5f0f6684aab9d9e9&hl=en) on the 'official' Picasa Web Album forum.

Looks like the best answer is to use an intermediary email forwarding service that doesn't require verification, such as [Gawab](http://www.gawab.com/webfront3/pkgs.php)

Comment: Though it's funny that google doesn't know that my gmail and my picasaweb autoforwarding mail belong to the same account.  They should make exceptions for these things

Comment: It's a common case of the left hand not talking to the right, which seems to be increasingly common in such a large company as Google.

Answer (score 2):

Within Gmail its going to be impossible since as you said, you do not get to see the text of the email inside of the Picasaweb dropbox, so you can't ever "verify" the forwarding address.

I've done something similar to this using a desktop client running in the background as another layer of filtering to do things that Gmail can't quite do yet.  e.g. [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) is what I use to do some extra filtering and header rewriting as needed. It doesn't require any sort of verification to forward to an address.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way around this if you have an apps account.  I use Google Apps accounts for different non-profits.

You can create a Group (photos@example.com) and forward to the Picasa address that is much longer.  Make sure to allow posting from the internet when you setup the group.  You can use the group address just like an email address.

Comment: This works great!  Nice workaround